# React Native - If / Else with a variable

Tags: react-native

I have to create two different variables (with the same name) as option for axios (the req data).

```
  var indentifiers = entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers;

  console.log(indentifiers.length);


  if (indentifiers.length === 1) {
    const item = {
      isbn_13: 'Not Provided',
      isbn_10: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
      kind: entry.kind,
      title: entry.volumeInfo.title,
      authors: entry.volumeInfo.authors,
      publishedDate: entry.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
      language: entry.volumeInfo.language,
      image1: entry.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    };
  } else if (indentifiers.length === 2) {
    const item = {
      isbn_13: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[1].identifier,
      isbn_10: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
      kind: entry.kind,
      title: entry.volumeInfo.title,
      authors: entry.volumeInfo.authors,
      publishedDate: entry.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
      language: entry.volumeInfo.language,
      image1: entry.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    };
  }
```

axios:

```
 const res = await axios.post(
        'http://74c26025c4e2.ngrok.io/api/database/addbook',
        item,
        config,
      );
```

Obviously when I put the variable into if/else is not reachable by the rest. What can I do?
thanks

Comment: Define it using `let` above the `if` statement, and mutate it accordingly

Comment: I tried but probably with the wrong syntax

Comment: Don't give up .

Comment: thanksa. lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if neither test succeed? You don't have a pure `else` statement in your example, so are you sure that `undefined` is allowed for `item`?

If so, as @marco-disco suggested, you can define a variable above your first `if` statement:

```js
let item
if (indentifiers.length === 1) {
    item = {
      isbn_13: 'Not Provided',
      isbn_10: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
      kind: entry.kind,
      title: entry.volumeInfo.title,
      authors: entry.volumeInfo.authors,
      publishedDate: entry.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
      language: entry.volumeInfo.language,
      image1: entry.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    };
  } else if (indentifiers.length === 2) {
    item = {
      isbn_13: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[1].identifier,
      isbn_10: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
      kind: entry.kind,
      title: entry.volumeInfo.title,
      authors: entry.volumeInfo.authors,
      publishedDate: entry.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
      language: entry.volumeInfo.language,
      image1: entry.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    };
  }
```

If you really want `item` to be a const, you can use a ternary operator:

```js
const item = (indentifiers.length === 1) ? {
    const item = {
      isbn_13: 'Not Provided',
      isbn_10: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
      kind: entry.kind,
      title: entry.volumeInfo.title,
      authors: entry.volumeInfo.authors,
      publishedDate: entry.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
      language: entry.volumeInfo.language,
      image1: entry.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    };
  } : (indentifiers.length === 2) ? {
    const item = {
      isbn_13: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[1].identifier,
      isbn_10: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
      kind: entry.kind,
      title: entry.volumeInfo.title,
      authors: entry.volumeInfo.authors,
      publishedDate: entry.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
      language: entry.volumeInfo.language,
      image1: entry.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    };
  } : undefined
```

or use an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression):

```js
const item = (() => {
  if (indentifiers.length === 1) {
    return {
      isbn_13: 'Not Provided',
      isbn_10: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
      kind: entry.kind,
      title: entry.volumeInfo.title,
      authors: entry.volumeInfo.authors,
      publishedDate: entry.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
      language: entry.volumeInfo.language,
      image1: entry.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    };
  } else if (indentifiers.length === 2) {
    return {
      isbn_13: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[1].identifier,
      isbn_10: entry.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier,
      kind: entry.kind,
      title: entry.volumeInfo.title,
      authors: entry.volumeInfo.authors,
      publishedDate: entry.volumeInfo.publishedDate,
      language: entry.volumeInfo.language,
      image1: entry.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
    };
  } else {
    return undefined
  }
})()
```